# Ansible Regex - include sub directory

Tags: ansible

I am not sure if what I desire is possible.

My goal is to match multiple patterns with regex via Ansible, including sub-directories.

```
- name: Find directories /tmp/test/hi and /tmp/test
  find:
    file_type: directory
    paths: /tmp
    use_regex: true
    patterns: "{{ item }}"
    recurse: yes
  register: foundFiles
  with_items:
    - ^(test) #returns value
    - (test.hi) #returns no value

  - debug: var=foundFiles
```

I tried several regular expresssions and tested it here http://regexr.com/ and here https://regex101.com/

Ansible keeps returning no value for /tmp/test/hi.

How do I specifically target /tmp/test/hi with a regex?

Answer (score 0):

This is because *test/hi* is not a directory, the directory is *hi* when module looks into *test* directory.

To fix your issue, you need to use:

```
with_items:
  - ^test
  - ^hi
```

Problem: all directory names that start with *hi* will be returned

Comment: Yes, exactly. Is there a possibility to only return the directory I want? Instead of all directories.

Comment: I tried and I not found a easily way. Maybe you should consider developing a new module that overloads the find module.

Comment: That is even harder. I created multiple tasks, to work around this issue. It's not a beauty, but get's the job done.

Comment: Just like me, I had also found a way with several tasks and saving temporary variables with the set_fact module.